# Google Drive: Change the name of the folder "My Drive"

Tags: windows, google-drive-api, windows-10

Is it possible to change the name of the folder "My Drive"?

[image: My Drive]

When I try to rename the folder, I get the following error message.

[image]

The error code did not help me.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to involve any computer programming. Share the code that calls the Google Drive API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that isn't possible for Google Drive for Desktop since the naming convention for these virtual drives are currently mapped to the directory architecture of the software itself.

I would suggest submitting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) for this.